# Firebase Gcloud : Service account, Private key generation error

Tags: android, ios, firebase, gcloud

i've an issue, when i try to generate a private key for a gcloud service account, i've the follwing error:  "erreur 400 : key creation is not allowed on this service account gcloud"

I don't know how to resolve this issue :-( , can you help me???

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

[The issue is the service account has been enforced role iam.disableServiceAccountKeyCreation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-service-accounts#disable_service_account_key_creation_2) please remove this role from the service account you are using currently.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i don't have this role... :-(
Another idea?

Comment: you can follow [Setting a boolean constraint](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-service-accounts#setting_a_boolean_constraint) to set iam.disableServiceAccountKeyCreation to False